# Maven web application - running Tomcat by sysdeo plugin not retrieving .properties

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, plugins

I am using Maven-spring-hibernate for a web application with modular approach, having JAR files for the different components and building them up into a web application at the end.

I have the following JAR which contains a META-INF folder with a property file (`database.properties`, with username/password).

```
common-model-1.0.0.jar
```

I have other component JAR's too, which are also using database connections.

```
common-service-1.0.0.jar
master-1.0.0.jar
master-model-1.0.0.jar
master-service-1.0.0.jar
```

When I deploy to the Tomcat started from the command line (catalina start/stop) the application works perfectly.

**But when I run Tomcat from inside Eclipse using Sysdeo Eclipse Tomcat plugin it throws the following exception**

```
Could not obtain connection to query metadata java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01005: null password given; logon denied
```

Is there any thing configuration that I might have missed?

When i debug jpa log found following

```
09:27:47,765 DEBUG [org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate] - Looking up JNDI object with name [dev.username]
09:27:47,765 DEBUG [org.springframework.jndi.JndiPropertySource] - JNDI lookup for name [dev.username] threw NamingException with message: Name dev.username is not bound in this Context. Returning null.
09:27:47,765 DEBUG [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] - Searching for key 'dev.username' in [systemProperties]
09:27:47,765 DEBUG [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] - Searching for key 'dev.username' in [systemEnvironment]
09:27:47,765 DEBUG [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] - Could not find key 'dev.username' in any property source. Returning [null]
09:27:47,765 DEBUG [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] - Searching for key 'dev.username' in [localProperties]
09:27:47,766 DEBUG [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] - Found key 'dev.username' in [localProperties] with type [String] and value 'cms_ownr'
09:27:47,766 DEBUG [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] - Searching for key 'dev.password' in [environmentProperties]
09:27:47,766 DEBUG [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] - Searching for key 'dev.password' in [servletConfigInitParams]
09:27:47,766 DEBUG [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] - Searching for key 'dev.password' in [servletContextInitParams]
09:27:47,766 DEBUG [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] - Searching for key 'dev.password' in [jndiProperties]
09:27:47,766 DEBUG [org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate] - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/dev.password]
09:27:47,766 DEBUG [org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate] - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/dev.password] not found - trying original name [dev.password]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name dev.password is not bound in this Context
09:27:47,766 DEBUG [org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate] - Looking up JNDI object with name [dev.password]
09:27:47,766 DEBUG [org.springframework.jndi.JndiPropertySource] - JNDI lookup for name [dev.password] threw NamingException with message: Name dev.password is not bound in this Context. Returning null.
09:27:47,767 DEBUG [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] - Searching for key 'dev.password' in [systemProperties]
09:27:47,767 DEBUG [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] - Searching for key 'dev.password' in [systemEnvironment]
09:27:47,767 DEBUG [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] - Could not find key 'dev.password' in any property source. Returning [null]
09:27:47,767 DEBUG [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] - Searching for key 'dev.password' in [localProperties]
09:27:47,767 DEBUG [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] - Found key 'dev.password' in [localProperties] with type [String] and value 'cms_ownr'
```

Comment: Can you run in debug mode to the point where you are trying to retrieve the database.properties file from the classpath - does this return null?

Comment: I have updated the question with log message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally my problem is resolved.

I had sts eclipse  with tomcat 6.x

I was using Sysdeo tomcatPluginV32.zip

Now i installed latest Sysdeo tomcatPluginV33.zip and it works fine now.